# Remote connection window closes immediately after login

Tags: remote, xrdp

I'm running Ubuntu desktop 23.04 on my Raspberry Pi. I have XRDP installed and rebooted the device since. On my Windows machine I have Kaspersky installed as anti-virus.

When I try to establish a remote connection on my Windows 10 computer using the remote desktop connection app (pre-installed) it shows the login screen and the xrdp logs seem to suggest that the connection was successfully established once I press ok. But the window (where the login screen was) turns black and closes shortly after. I don't see anything from the desktop environment of the Raspberry Pi and no error messages are displayed.

I had no ssh connection to the Pi, there was no display connected to it.

Here are the XRDP logs incase it might help

```
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:192.168.1.115 port 60993
[20230803-18:44:54] [ERROR] [MCS Connection Sequence] receive connection request failed
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20230803-18:44:54] [ERROR] xrdp_sec_incoming: xrdp_mcs_incoming failed
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20230803-18:44:54] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_incoming: xrdp_sec_incoming failed
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] Security protocol: configured [SSL|RDP], requested [SSL|HYBRID|HYBRID_EX|RDP], selected [SSL]
[20230803-18:44:54] [ERROR] xrdp_process_main_loop: libxrdp_process_incoming failed
[20230803-18:44:54] [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
[20230803-18:44:54] [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] Connected client computer name: DESKTOP-GRI7EL3
[20230803-18:44:54] [WARN ] Received [MS-RDPBCGR] TS_UD_HEADER type 0xc006 is unknown (ignored)
[20230803-18:44:54] [WARN ] Received [MS-RDPBCGR] TS_UD_HEADER type 0xc00a is unknown (ignored)
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: Keyboard information sent by the RDP client, keyboard_type:[0x04], keyboard_subtype:[0x00], keylayout:[0x00000807]
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [] variant [] layout [ch] options []
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff:192.168.1.115 port 60993: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 10485760 MB cache entries 100
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
[20230803-18:44:54] [WARN ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
[20230803-18:44:54] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000807.ini
[20230803-18:44:54] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000807 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] connecting to sesman on 127.0.0.1:3350
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] sesman connect ok
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] sending login info to session manager. Please wait...
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for user lukas on display 10
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] login successful for user lukas on display 10
[20230803-18:45:00] [INFO ] loaded module 'libxup.so' ok, interface size 10296, version 4
[20230803-18:45:01] [INFO ] started connecting
[20230803-18:45:01] [INFO ] lib_mod_connect: connecting via UNIX socket
[20230803-18:45:01] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=2739 connected to X11rdp_pid=2743 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:192.168.1.115 client_port=60993
[20230803-18:45:01] [INFO ] connected ok
```